# Prove by contradiction that: $A∩B=B∩A$. Is my proof right?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Prove by contradiction that: $A∩B=B∩A$.

**My Solution:** Assume to the contrary that

$A∩B ≠ B∩A$  .... (i)

Consequently, $B∩A≠ A∩B$ ...... (ii).

Since for all sets $A$ and $B$ ,  $A=B → B=A$.

Then, (i) and (ii) as a whole suggest $A∩B≠A∩B$.

The foregoing statement contradicts the fact that for every set $A$ , $A = A$.

By such an antilogy we've shown that $B∩A = A∩B$.

---

Recently enrolled for math major. I try and devising my proving skills before the first day.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Just because $x\ne y$ and $y\ne z$, it does not follow that $x\ne z$, so your proof is flawed

Comment: I understand, cheers :D

Comment: Indeed, your proof uses nothing specific of sets, therefore if it worked, then it would work for anything, and thus prove that nothing is ever equal to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
x \in A \cap B &\iff (x \in A) \land (x \in B)\\
&\iff (x\in B) \land (x \in A)\\
&\iff x \in B \cap A,
\end{align}$$

where I used that the logical "AND" $\land$ is commutative. Thus we conclude $A\cap B = B \cap A.$

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a proof by contradiction? It's fairly easy to do it like this:

Let $x\in A\cap B$. Then of course $x\in B$, and $x\in A$, ie, $x\in B\cap A$. Thus $A\cap B\subset B\cap A$

Now let $x\in B\cap A$. Then $x\in A$, and $x\in B$, so $x\in A\cap B$. Thus $B\cap A\subset A\cap B$

$A\cap B\subset B\cap A$ and $B\cap A \subset A\cap B$, so $A\cap B = B\cap A$

You could modify this quite easily to do a proof by contradiction, it would just be an odd way I'd think.

In general the easiest way to prove equality between 2 sets is to show that each is contained in the other, through the use of an arbitrary element.